# Синхронизация скроллов на javascript

Tags: javascript

Господа фронтендеры, прошу помощи! Нашел такой вот скрипт. Требуется верхний слайдер синхронизировать со скроллом в блоке, что находится под ним. То есть когда тягаю мышкой слайдер, чтоб скроллился блок. И если буду блок скроллить отдельно от слайдера, чтоб слайдер тоже скроллился. Подскажите и помогите начинающему, пожалуйста

[Ссылка на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgyb10t5/5/)

```
var sliderElem = document.getElementById('slider');
var thumbElem = sliderElem.children[0];
var container = document.getElementById('container')

thumbElem.onmousedown = function(e) {
  var thumbCoords = getCoords(thumbElem);
  var shiftX = e.pageX - thumbCoords.left;

  var sliderCoords = getCoords(sliderElem);

  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var newLeft = e.pageX - shiftX - sliderCoords.left;

    if (newLeft < 0) {
      newLeft = 0;
    }
    var rightEdge = sliderElem.offsetWidth - thumbElem.offsetWidth;
    if (newLeft > rightEdge) {
      newLeft = rightEdge;
    }

    thumbElem.style.left = newLeft + 'px';
  }

  document.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
  };

  return false;
};

thumbElem.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};

function getCoords(elem) { // кроме IE8-
  var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    top: box.top + pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + pageXOffset
  };

}
```

Comment: Я примерно понимаю, что надо парсить высоту дива, который надо скроллить. И парсить ширину слайдера. И делить их в процентном соотношении. Но не могу разобраться, как это добавить в скрипт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно менять положение слайдера на событие изменения скролла **container.onscroll**. И добавить изменение скролла при изменении позиции слайдера.

```js
var sliderElem = document.getElementById('slider');
var thumbElem = sliderElem.children[0];
var container = document.getElementById('container')

thumbElem.onmousedown = function(e) {
  var thumbCoords = getCoords(thumbElem);
  var shiftX = e.pageX - thumbCoords.left;

  var sliderCoords = getCoords(sliderElem);

  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var newLeft = e.pageX - shiftX - sliderCoords.left;

    if (newLeft < 0) {
      newLeft = 0;
    }
    var rightEdge = sliderElem.offsetWidth - thumbElem.offsetWidth;
    if (newLeft > rightEdge) {
      newLeft = rightEdge;
    }
    
    var scrollPercent = newLeft/rightEdge;
    container.scrollTop = (container.scrollHeight - container.offsetHeight)*scrollPercent

    thumbElem.style.left = newLeft + 'px';
  }

  document.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = document.onmouseup = null;
  };

  return false;
};

thumbElem.ondragstart = function() {
  return false;
};

container.onscroll = function (e) {  
  var scrollPercent = container.scrollTop/(container.scrollHeight - container.offsetHeight);
  var rightEdge = sliderElem.offsetWidth - thumbElem.offsetWidth;
  thumbElem.style.left = Math.floor(rightEdge*scrollPercent) + 'px';
}

function getCoords(elem) { // кроме IE8-
  var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    top: box.top + pageYOffset,
    left: box.left + pageXOffset
  };

}
```

```css
.slider {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #E0E0E0;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left top, #E0E0E0, #EEEEEE) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from(#E0E0E0), to(#EEEEEE));
  background: linear-gradient(left top, #E0E0E0, #EEEEEE);
  width: 310px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.thumb {
  width: 10px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
  top: -5px;
  background: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container {
  width: 310px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 30px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider" class="slider">
  <div class="thumb"></div>
</div>

<div id="container" class="container">
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

P.S.: советую вынести переменные, которые используются во всех функциях наружу, что бы они не пересчитывались. (а именно размеры блоков)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!) То, что нужно) Вот [ссылка на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgyb10t5/6/) с готовым рабочим вариантом. Может кому то пригодится